# How to use MapStruct to update an immutable field inline?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm using MapStruct to transfer data from one bean to another and I'm struggling with copying data into an immutable inner field of the target object. In particular the inner immutable field is a Guava multimap:

```
// Source.java

import com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap;

public class Source
{
    private final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> info = LinkedHashMultimap.create();

    public LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }

}
```

```
// Target.java

import com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap;

public class Target
{
    private final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> info = LinkedHashMultimap.create();

    public LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }

}
```

A basic mapper from Source to Target doesn't see the `info` field:

```
// BasicTargetMapper.java

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;

import com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap;

@Mapper
public interface BasicTargetMapper
{

    default void copyMultimap(final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> sourceMap,
            @MappingTarget final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> targetMap)
    {
        if (sourceMap != null) {
            targetMap.putAll(sourceMap);
        }
    }

    Target toTarget(Source source);
}

// Generated BasicTargetMapperImpl.java

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-03-10T11:43:53+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_221 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
public class BasicTargetMapperImpl implements BasicTargetMapper {

    @Override
    public Target toTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        return target;
    }
}
```

Forcing the copy of the field results in a compilation error:

```
// ForcedTargetMapper.java

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;
import org.mapstruct.Named;

import com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap;

@Mapper
public interface ForcedTargetMapper
{

    @Named("copyMultimap")
    default void copyMultimap(final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> sourceMap,
            @MappingTarget final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> targetMap)
    {
        if (sourceMap != null) {
            targetMap.putAll(sourceMap);
        }
    }

    @Mapping(target = "info", qualifiedByName = "copyMultimap")
    Target toTarget(Source source);
}
```

Compilation produces: `Property "info" has no write accessor in Target.`

The solution that I found so far is to use `@AfterMapping` like this:

```
// TargetMapper.java

import org.mapstruct.AfterMapping;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;

import com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap;

@Mapper
public interface TargetMapper
{

    default void copyMultimap(final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> sourceMap,
            final LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> targetMap)
    {
        if (sourceMap != null) {
            targetMap.putAll(sourceMap);
        }
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void finishCopy(final Source source, @MappingTarget final Target target)
    {
        copyMultimap(source.getInfo(), target.getInfo());
    }

    @Mapping(target = "info", ignore = true)
    Target toTarget(Source source);
}

// Generated TargetMapperImpl.java

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-03-10T11:55:42+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_221 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
public class TargetMapperImpl implements TargetMapper {

    @Override
    public Target toTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        finishCopy( source, target );

        return target;
    }
}
```

Is there a more practical solution to this problem?
The same question arises if the target field is an Hibernate persisted collection and you want to modify it in-place (e.g.: to remove already persisted entities, update existing entities and/or add new ones).